# Short story about a gigantic space monster that is big enough to cover half of the Earth

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I was looking for a short story I read a while ago but I think is an old scifi story (maybe from the 1960s). It's about some sort of space creature that resembles a lizard that jumps from deeper space to the Earth. The monster is big enough to sit over half the world and it seems invulnerable to any kind of attack. If I remember right, at the end of the story the creature just jumps leaving an almost destroyed planet behind.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Brian Aldiss: "[Heresies Of The Huge God](http://www.scifi.darkroastedblend.com/2008/01/1966-year-in-sf-august.html)" © Galaxy, Aug 1966

There's some confusion as to exactly what the thing was. Some call it a lizard, others a moth, still others claim it was a machine. Aldiss was probably less than clear, deliberately, when he wrote the story.